# Apache as Proxy: how to configure TLS on the downstream side?

Tags: apache

We want to use an Apache2 (v2.4.51) as a (reverse) proxy to access a downstream server (running Tomcat). That Tomcat is configured to accept only TLS v1.2 and a very limited set of ciphers (and that's not negotiable).

In the logs I found that our Apache tries to open the connection to that Tomcat using TLS v1.3 which causes the downstream server to immediately terminate the connection and no further communication happens.

How can I configure an Apache server to use a specific TLS version and cipher on an *outgoing*/ *downstream* connection? Everything I found re. Apache TLS configuration so far was dealing with the *front*-side, i.e. what Apache receives and accepts. But in my case I need to adjust the back-end-side, i.e. what Apache uses when it forwards a request.

How/where can one configure that?

Edit: Meanwhile I realized that the terms "upstream" & "downstream" are not always used consistently - so just in case: with "downstream" here I mean the connection (2) as sketched below:

{browsers/internet} --(1)--> [Apache reverse proxy] --(2)--> [Tomcat application server].

Edit 2: In Tomcat's log (catalina.out) I keep getting the below exception which seems to suggest that it is addressed using TLS v1.3 (which it can't handle):

```
Oct 06, 2022 5:22:06 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint setSocketOptions
SEVERE: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:171)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshakeContext.<init>(ServerHandshakeContext.java:62)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:220)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.beginHandshake(SSLEngineImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.reset(SecureNioChannel.java:89)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.<init>(SecureNioChannel.java:71)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.setSocketOptions(NioEndpoint.java:666)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:808)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

javax.net.ssl|FINE|B5|http-nio-8443-Acceptor-0|2022-10-06 17:22:07.539 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:304|No available cipher suite for TLS13
javax.net.ssl|SEVERE|B5|http-nio-8443-Acceptor-0|2022-10-06 17:22:07.540 CEST|TransportContext.java:316|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Couldn't kickstart handshaking (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:171)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshakeContext.<init>(ServerHandshakeContext.java:62)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:220)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.beginHandshake(SSLEngineImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.reset(SecureNioChannel.java:89)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.<init>(SecureNioChannel.java:71)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.setSocketOptions(NioEndpoint.java:666)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:808)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)}
```

Edit 3: my `/etc/apache2/conf.d/proxy.conf` file now reads:

```
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile -name-removed-
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile -name-removed-
    ProxyPass /foobar https://-name-removed-:8443/foobar
    ProxyPassReverse /foobar https://-name-removed-:8443/foobar

    SSLProxyProtocol +TLSv1.2
    
    <Proxy "*">
        Require all granted
        SSLProxyProtocol +TLSv1.2
    </Proxy>
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog "-name-removed-"
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: "foobar" and "-name-removed-" represent values that I replaced for privacy.

Edit 4:
The nmap response was:

```
# nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 8443 127.0.0.1
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-10-10 16:12 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00011s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE    VERSION
8443/tcp open  tcpwrapped

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.67 seconds
#
```

What does that tell me?

Comment: I’m not certain but it might help to review [`mod_ssl`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html)’s proxy handling. The `SSLProxyEngine` directive might be a good place to start.

Comment: I went through that (already beforehand but now again) and the only option here that looks promising is `SSLProtocol +TLSv1.2` but that apparently controls the *front* end only, i.e. what is acceptable when a client (i.e. a browser) connects to that Apache acting as reverse proxy. It doesn't seem to influence the *out-going* onward connection to the downstream Tomcat server (at least I see in that Tomcat's log that it gets connected to requesting a TLS v1.3 connection and thus rejects and disconnects).

Comment: There is also a [`SSLProxyProtocol`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxyprotocol) for your review

Comment: That looked indeed promising (why haven't I spotted that so far?). I tried to specify that inside the <VirtualHost>-element and also inside the nested <Proxy>-element but it seems to have no effect. On the Tomcat server I keep getting the exception that it can't handle TLS v1.3 (since I could not append the exception stack trace in a comment I added it to the question above - see "Edit 2").

Comment: First thing you need to find out is which Java version Tomcat is using, guessing possible ciphers and protocol from there should be easier. And then you just rely on SSLProxyXXXXX directives to specify what this backend needs.

Comment: The Tomcat is v7.0.41 running on top of Java 8.0.322 (jdk8u322-b06).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest running a utility like nmap to assess the SSL capabilities of the backend server (Tomcat) in this instance. nmap nicely prints out the TLS protocols and ciphers that a given TLS server supports. Using this information, we could configure Apache HTTPD to use the same protocols and ciphers for the backend connection using SSLProxyProtocol and SSLProxyCipherSuite directives.

How to use nmap:
nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p

Comment: Since one can't decently format comments I added the result as "Edit 4" above. But it doesn't seem to reveal a lot, does it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved! I had a typo in the config file! Shame on me and sorry for the bandwidth consumed.